# C++ function resolution matches different function when I adjust their sequence

Tags: c++, templates, overloading, overload-resolution

I've got a test program to see how compiler(g++) match template function:

```
#include<stdio.h>
template<class T>void f(T){printf("T\n");}
template<class T>void f(T*){printf("T*\n");}
template<>       void f(int*){printf("int*\n");}
int main(int argc,char**) {
    int *p = &argc;
    f(p); // int*
    return 0;
}
```

It prints `int*`. Seems the specialized template is the high priority match? Then I switched the function declaration a bit, this time:

```
#include<stdio.h>
template<class T>void f(T){printf("T\n");}
template<>       void f(int*){printf("int*\n");}
template<class T>void f(T*){printf("T*\n");}
int main(int argc,char**) {
    int *p = &argc;
    f(p); // T*
    return 0;
}
```

It prints `T*`. The only difference between the 2 programs is I changed the function declaration for overloaded "f" a bit, why the result is different?

Comment: It's more, or less, the same reason why C++ developers, on average, consume much more coffee, or alcohol, or both, than everyone else.

Comment: To be fair to your compiler, you aren't really giving it clarity as to which specialization it chooses. Seems to me that the last one in the list is probably as good a choice as the first.

Comment: And for the record, MSVC does the same.

Comment: FWIW, this is one of the few things that the C++ standards explicitly [warns](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.expl.spec#8) about (and does so in a humorous way): *When writing a specialization, be careful about its location; or to make it compile will be such a trial as to kindle its self-immolation.* :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have two (overloaded) template functions here, and a third function `f(int*)` that is specializing one of the template functions.

The specialization happens after after the overload resolution.  So in both cases you will select `f(T*)` over `f(T)`.  However, in the first case when you have specialized `f(T*)`, you will get the `int*` specialization.  In the second case, when you have specialized `f(T)`, the selected function has no specialization.

Remember that you can't partially-specialize a template function, only fully specialize it.  If you want `f` always to print `int*`, then consider making `f(int*)` a regular function, rather than a template specialization.